# How to save/display multiple sessions on tensorboard?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to run/optimize my Tensorflow graph with different parameters, and see the summaries side by side on tensorboard. How is it possible?

I saw in the presentation, that somehow they gave different colors and titles to each session

Comment: Did you try setting `--logdir` to the root folder containing all your run logs? (Ideally each run has its own subfolder)